# Swift GDC background process freezes app

Tags: swift, cocoa, background, dispatch-async

I've written the function that launches Tor process. It's a process that won't stop until SIGTERM is sent to it, so, to avoid app freezing, I run this process in a background queue (Tor needs to be launched when the application is started and finished when application is terminated, and user needs to do some other things meanwhile). That's my code for Tor launching:

```
func launchTor(hashedPassword hash : String) {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0)) {
        let task = NSTask()
        task.launchPath = "/bin/bash"
        print("Hashed password : \(hash)")
        task.arguments = (["-c", "/usr/local/bin/tor HashedControlPassword \(hash)"])

        let pipe = NSPipe()
        task.standardOutput = pipe
        let handle = pipe.fileHandleForReading
        handle.waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify()

        let errPipe = NSPipe()
        task.standardError = errPipe
        let errHandle = errPipe.fileHandleForReading
        errHandle.waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify()

        var startObserver : NSObjectProtocol!
        startObserver = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(NSFileHandleDataAvailableNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { notification -> Void in
            let data = handle.availableData
            if data.length > 0 {
                if let output = String(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
                    print("Output : \(output)")
                }
            }
            else {
                print("EOF on stdout")
                NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(startObserver)
            }
        }

        var endObserver : NSObjectProtocol!
        endObserver = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(NSTaskDidTerminateNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) {
            notification -> Void in
            print("Task terminated with code \(task.terminationStatus)")
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(endObserver)
        }

        var errObserver : NSObjectProtocol!
        errObserver = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(NSTaskDidTerminateNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) {
            notification -> Void in
            let data = errHandle.availableData
            if (data.length > 0) {
                if let output = String(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
                    print("Error : \(output)")

                    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(errObserver)
                }
            }
        }

        task.launch()

        _ = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName("AppTerminates", object: nil, queue: nil) {
            notification -> Void in
            task.terminate()
        }
        task.waitUntilExit()
    }
}
```

When it's launched, everything is OK, but then the whole app freezes. When I stop an app, I always see that `let data = handle.availableData` line is running. How to fix this issue?

Comment: Have you checked what the queue this task was performed in? I'm not sure this was background one.

Comment: @Astoria, It was in a background. My latest fix - I just commented all output and still wait for other solutions